# QtQuick TableView and QSqlTableModel not working

Tags: sql, qt, qml

I am trying to implement a QML program to view data in a database. I am using QSqlTableModel as model and TableView for visualization. The point is that TableView doesn't call the data function at all, so I only see a bunch of empty rows ( it is able to correctly count the number of rows in the model ). As you will se below, the model works perfectly when used with QTableView. So the point is that TableView doesn't call data at all.

This is the code. QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 640
    title: qsTr("myApp")

    TableView {
        sortIndicatorVisible: true
        model: sqlData
        anchors.fill: parent

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "Nome"
            title: "Nome"
            width: 200
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "Residenza"
            title: "Residenza"
            width: 200
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "Assicurazione"
            title: "Assicurazione"
            width: 200
        }
    }
}
```

C++ Header file

```
#ifndef LISTMODEL_H
#define LISTMODEL_H

#include <QtSql/QSqlTableModel>
#include <QHash>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QModelIndex>

class ListModel: public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY ( QString sqlFilter READ getSQLFilter WRITE setSQLFilter )
private:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    QString getSQLFilter() { return filter(); }
    void setSQLFilter(const QString &filter) { setFilter(filter); }

public:
    explicit ListModel(QObject *parent = 0);

public:
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const;
    void generateRoleNames();

#ifdef HAVE_QT5
    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const{return roles;}
#endif
};

#endif // LISTMODEL_H
```

Implementation

```
#include "listmodel.h"
#include <QtSql/QSqlRecord>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QModelIndex>

ListModel::ListModel(QObject *parent) : QSqlTableModel(parent) {

}

QVariant ListModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role ) const
{
    if(index.row() >= rowCount())
        return QVariant();

    if(role < Qt::UserRole)
        return QSqlTableModel::data(index, role);

    QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), role - Qt::UserRole - 1);
    return QSqlTableModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
}

void ListModel::generateRoleNames()
{
    roles.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount(); i++)
    {
        roles[Qt::UserRole + i + 1] = QVariant(headerData(i, Qt::Horizontal)).toByteArray();
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <listmodel.h>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QTableView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString dbName(app.applicationDirPath());
    dbName.append("/mydb.sqlite");

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, qApp->tr("Cannot open database"), "", QMessageBox::Cancel);
        return 0;
    }

    ListModel dataModel;
    dataModel.setTable("Clienti");
    dataModel.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
    dataModel.select();
    dataModel.generateRoleNames();

    while(dataModel.canFetchMore())
        dataModel.fetchMore();
/*
    QTableView *myView = new QTableView;
    myView->setModel( dataModel );
    myView->show();
*/
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("sqlData", &dataModel);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Where do we get the Material module? Can't run your code without it.

Comment: Never mind, made it work. Let me know if I took too much code away.

Comment: The material style is from papyros https://github.com/papyros/qml-material. In regard to my question, I can only say "screw you ifdef". HAVE_QT5 wasn't set up, so there was no method roleNames in the binary. I thought setting the macro was responsibility of QtCreator.